# Creating a Windows checkbox in a VBScript that will be executed by cscript.exe

Tags: windows, user-interface, scripting, vbscript, wsh

If I have a [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) like...

```
inputControl1 = InputBox("Hello World")
WScript.Quit
```

How can a check box be created in there rather then the InputBox?

I know VBScript itself does not have a checkbox control like the InputBox, but is there some library I can use to do something like the following?

```
inputControl1 = CreateObject("library.checkboxcontrol")
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you use a yes/no msgbox instead?

```
dim Answer
Answer=msgbox("Your question here",4)
```

Comment: I tried this and will probably go with it even though it's really not what I was looking for. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an HTA.  That would be more involved than a VBScript, but it would be written in VBScript + HTML.  There would be a few IE restrictions you may have to work around though.

Alternatively if you get VB.NET Express and code using that.  It is a different language of course.